# Отношение JScript к разным программам

Tags: jscript

День добрый! Мне нужно было написать код .js, в котором может быть параметр, в котором могут быть пробелы. Ну, с передачей параметра .js я справился. Все работало на ять до тех пор, пока я не дошел до проверки реакции моего .js на параметр с пробелом(-ами). Он не сработал. Тогда я вообще пока отошел от параметра и начал привлекать разные программы. И вот что обнаружил. На такой код:

```
WshShell=
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
//WshShell.Run("""not pro.doc""");
WshShell.Run("Explorer " + "C:\\Program 
Files");
WshShell.Run("AcroRd32 " +  
"C:\\pre view.pdf");
WshShell.Run("C:\\preview.pdf");
WshShell.Run("C:\\not pro.doc");
```

следующая реакция: первая команда выполняется без каких-либо нареканий, на вторую команду вообще никакой реакции, третья команда как первая, а на четвертую ругается, что файл не найден. Попробуйте, пожалуйста, кто-нибудь выполнить этот код и скажите, это только у меня так или так и должно быть?
[вот здесь](http://www.spravkaweb.ru/jscript/methods/dateparse) написано, что

> И запятые, и пробелы используются как разделители. Допускаются множественные разделители

хотя это и про другое, но я вот смотрю на реакцию на тот, первый .js (пока его код неважен) и понимаю, что и у меня пробел воспринимается как разделитель. А как тогда правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WshShell.Run("AcroRd32 \"C:\\pre view.pdf\"");
```

---

> А как быть, если нужно использовать аргумент с пробелом? Пробовал так:
>
> ```
> WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
> var objArgs; 
> objArgs = WScript.Arguments; 
> WScript.Echo(objArgs(0)); 
> WshShell.Run("winword \"objArgs(0)\"");
> ```
>
> но не пошло: аргумент выводит, а файл не находит.

Надо вставлять в команду *значение* `objArgs(0)`:

```
WshShell.Run(`winword \"${objArgs(0)}\"`);
```

> вы ничего не путаете

Хорошо, тогда напишите

```
WshShell.Run("winword \"" + objArgs(0) + "\"");
```

Comment: igor, угу, большое спасибо. А как быть, если нужно использовать аргумент с пробелом? Пробовал так: WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
var objArgs;
objArgs = WScript.Arguments;
WScript.Echo(objArgs(0));
WshShell.Run("winword \"objArgs(0)\""); но не пошло: аргумент выводит, а файл не находит.

Answer (score 0):

Это пишет ТС. Я не могу писать в комментарии, потому что только что повторно зарегистрировался по причине, указанной [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1011899/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC/1011903#1011903). igor, а вы ничего не путаете? Реакция на ваш код такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модераторы, исправьте, пожалуйста, это сообщение. Сейчас я с Хромом разберусь и больше не буду так делать.

> WshShell.Run("winword \"" + objArgs(0) + "\"");

Вот это работает, спасибо.

Comment: А почему ваш первый вариант не сработал у меня? Ведь, очевидно, у вас этот код работает, иначе зачем бы вы мне его дали? Это, а вы не могли бы порекомендовать литературу, где бы прилично описывался JS? Чтобы были команды в духе рекомендованных вами  в этой теме команд? А то попадается ерунда наподобие "Командные файлы и сценарии WSH", а приличного ничего. И на МСДН что-то не могу найти.

Comment: Очевидно, среда не поддерживает строки "template literals".

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос: "Это, а вы не могли бы порекомендовать литературу, где бы прилично описывался JS?..."

Comment: Да, не ответил. Нет, не мог бы.

Comment: Ну, вы же сами откуда-то знаете.